# BigCommerce Order Create

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using basic auth and trying to create an order vi the api. I get a 400 response. How can I debug this? What can I do to get an indication of what is wrong with what I am sending?
All other api calls I make are working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that the response had a pretty good message describing the problem. I missed it at first.